# Confusing of CodeIgniter routes

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my route:

```
$route['pages/show_create']['GET'] = 'pages/show_create';
$route['pages/create']['POST'] = 'pages/create';
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function show_create()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Create new news';     
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/create');
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $data['title'] = 'Create new news';
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('text', 'Text', 'required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('news/create');
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->news_model->set_news();
            $this->load->view('news/success');
        }
    }
```

I want to show the form by accessing `news/show_create` route but it just return 404. What's wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: Please remove ['get'] from route. Just use $route['pages/show_create'] = 'pages/show_create';

Answer (score 1):

Codeigniter documentation is very easiest programming documentation. You can easily learn more about routing by using following link.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

As i can see in your code you don't need to mentioned method type along with route.

Here i am assuming that you have got and PagesController class where you have created a method by using name show_create and for this you can set routing like below in your route class.If still you have confusion you can write here.

$route['news/show_create'] = 'pages/show_create';

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your routes.

```
$route['news/show_create']['GET'] = 'pages/show_create';
```

I assumed your controller name is PageController.

This is the format.

```
$route['desired_route']['method'] = 'controller_name/function';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$route['news/show_create']='Controller_name/method_name';
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need routes. If they are removed, and assuming the controller is named `pages`, you can call the methods like so

`http://example.com/pages/show_create`

and

`http://example.com/pages/create`

If you truly want to show the form by accessing `news/show_create` then `$route` in Girraj's answer is the way to go.

`$route['news/show_create'] = 'pages/show_create';`